# How to hide some tabs in header filter in Ag-Grid?

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I have Auto Column Groups and I need to hide some tabs. 
I can't find it in the documentation, maybe you can help me. Documentation https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-grouping/

I want to hide selected tabs. Is it possible?

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by `tab`?

Comment: @Paritosh Do you see 3 buttons? They work as tabs, so when you click on the button it shows some content with filter, sorting etc.

Answer (score 0):

this does what you want but it requires Ag-Grid enterprise license
https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/column-menu/#showing-the-column-menu

Documentation says:
The property menuTabs is an array of strings. The valid values are: 'filterMenuTab', 'generalMenuTab' and 'columnsMenuTab'.

generalMenuTab: Include to show the main panel.
filterMenuTab: Include to show the filter panel.
columnsMenuTab: Include to show the column selection panel.
To not show the menu at all, set this property to an empty array[].

Just choose which tabs you want like this: menuTabs: ['filterMenuTab']